# How to append html text to JLabel in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to append text with HTML tags to text that is already in a JLabel and also has HTML tags

```
public class BattleConsoleUI {
    private JLabel battleInfo = new JLabel("<html> Hello World <br></html>");

battleInfo.setText(battleInfo.getText() + 
            "<html> HERO NAME :   " +
            "<br> HERO CLASS      :   "  +
            "<br> HERO LEVEL      :   "  +
            "<br> XP              :   "  +
            "<br> ATTACK POINTS   :   "  +
            "<br> DEFENCE POINTS  :   "  +
            "<br> HIT POINTS      :   "  + 
            "</html>");
}
```

I'm expecting it to display Hello World plus the appended text but the rest of the text is not displayed because of the first closing HTML tag

Comment: typo: `battleInfo.setText(battleInfo.getText() + ....`. Also you may wish to have the `html` tags before & after your text body

Comment: Maybe a `JTable` would be better here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick solution is to avoid writing `</html>` at the end of the text. Swing needs only the opening tag `<html>` in order to show HTML text. Something like:

```
label.setText("<html>first text");
label.setText(label.getText() + " this is second"); //Still an HTML text
```

If you insist of closing the HTML tag and using `</html>` at the end, you will have to replace it before appending the new text:

```
label.setText(label.getText().replaceAll("</html>","") + "i append a text</html>");
```

Of course instead of `replaceAll` you could use `substring` and other things, but this is what i would use.

Comment: Thanks a lot George. The  first solution worked perfectly without the closing tag. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Tsundzukani I am glad that i helped. However i see you are a new member. Take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You are making the variable itself to be first set and then again inside that get text. You can do simple thing is that make two different string variable and set them to jlabel. As per here you can :

```
String htmlstr1 = "html hello world tag";

String htmlstr2 = "<html> HERO NAME :   "
    +
                "<br> HERO CLASS      :   "  +
                "<br> HERO LEVEL      :   "  +
                "<br> XP              :   "  +
                "<br> ATTACK POINTS   :   "  +
                "<br> DEFENCE POINTS  :   "  +
                "<br> HIT POINTS      :   "  + "</html>");
Jlabel.setText(htmlstr1+htmlstr2):
```

Comment: I need to keep appending different strings during the course of the game. It would be more than 2 strings. I found the solution though. Thank you.

Comment: Can you give just upvote ?? It help me alot . Thanks

Comment: I cannot upvote yet. I'm on level 8. I can only be able to upvote once I reach level 15

Comment: What do I need to do to improve my level?

Comment: You can suggest edit as I do and answer most of question you know, also make you self active here. Visit badges page you will get to know more.

Comment: Ok Dharmik. I'll Do so.